# How to make alert for new version on theme options?

Tags: themes, php, theme-options, wordpress-version

Let say my theme host on my server. User download my theme and use it. Now I want notify @ alert for new version of my theme.

Example to show "New version has been release. Please download at ..."

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see:

http://clark-technet.com/2010/12/wordpress-self-hosted-plugin-update-api

Basically the idea is to hook your update checking function to the `pre_set_site_transient_update_themes` filter. The version array key you return from this function will be compared by WP to the current theme version from style.css....

Use the `admin_notices` action to make your alert message more noticeable